# Observable of array, find index of value

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs5

I'm writing an Angular app that gets a selection of stores from a service, as an Observable.

When the user clicks a marker on the map, I want to get the index of the store in the array that lives inside the Observable.

```
stores: Observable<Store[]>;

ngOnInit() {
    this.stores = http.get<Store[]>('URL');
}

onMarkerClick(event) {
   const geopoint = event.geopoint;
   //How can I get the index where store.geopoint === event.geopoint?
}
```

Comment: If this is a bad question, please let me know why instead of just downvoting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For filtering the stores from the array you do:

```
this.storesCollection.filter(store => store.geopoint === event.geopoint); // -1 if not found
```

And for transforming the Observable to an Array use map:

```
this.stores$.map((stores: Stores[]) => this.storesCollection = stores)
```

You don't need to do subscribe() because http returns a hot observable, always firing regardless of there being a subscriber or not

Comment: @Mark van Straten Ah yes, I added the part about mapping to a value. Next time you are welcome to comment on an incomplete answer without downvoting

Answer (score 1):

If you want to lazily get your `store[]` from your backend you will have to fetch these upon the first subscribe to the `this.stores`. All other subscribes may use the same values returned from your `http.get`. To accomplish this we can use `.shareReplay()` to have all subscribers multicast to the same source and have it replay its previous values instead of re-invoking `http.get`

```js
function getStores() {
  //return http.get<Store[]>(URL) 
  return Rx.Observable.from(['asdf', 'foo', 'bar']).delay(500);
}

const stores = getStores()
  .do(undefined, undefined, _ => console.log('retrieved values from http backend'))
  .shareReplay();
const $buttonClicks = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(document.getElementById('button'), 'click');

$buttonClicks
  .do(_ => console.log('CLICKED'))
  .switchMap(_ => stores
               .map((val, idx) => [val, idx])
               .filter(tuple => tuple[0] === 'foo')
               .map(tuple => tuple[1])
            )
  .subscribe(
    idx => console.log('got index of `foo`: ' + idx)
  );
```

The switchMap is a bit ugly (map/filter/map) because this example code does not utilise an array but instead single emissions. `.toArray()` can fix this. Depends on how you want to proceed with using the index (or value)

Comment: Thanks, this is perfect!