# How to Fetch Data from JSON multiple array(live data from DB) using observable in Angular2

Tags: json, angular2-services

JSON response is as below:

```
{
    "clientInfo": [
        {
            "clientId": "1234",
            "clientName": "Test1234"
        },
        {
            "clientId": "4356",
            "clientName": "Test4356"
        }],
    "realTimeClientInfo": [
        {
            "clientId": "1234",
            "clientName": "Test1234",
           "Location": "Test1234",
            "Designation" :"Test1234"

        },
        {
            "clientId": "4356",
            "clientName": "Test7896",
           "Location": "Test7896",
            "Designation" :"Test7896"
        }]
        }
```

I want to fetch the data from the second JSON array.

In client.component.ts invoke the clientService as below:

```
@Input() clientInfo$: Observable<any>;
constructor(private clientService: ClientService) { }

 ngOnInit() {  this.clientInfo$ = Observable
                            .interval(1000)
                            .startWith(0).switchMap(() => 
  this.clientService.getAllInfo()); }
```

client.service.ts is as below :

```
getAllInfo(): Observable<ClientInfo[]> {
    this.http.get<ClientInfo[]>('http://localhost:8080/api/auth/clientInfo');
```

In client.component.html

```
                <table class="table table-hover">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th *ngFor="let col of clientH">{{ col }}</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr *ngFor="let client of clientInfo$ | async ">
                            <td *ngFor="let col of clientH"> {{client [col]}}</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
```

If the JSON contains only one single array this is working. How we can use the same logic to retrieve some values from first array and some other values from the second array

Comment: Please refer these links. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40495483/how-to-find-an-element-of-an-array-by-id-with-observable-in-angular2 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46700055/angular-httpclient-map-get-method-object-result-to-array-property https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50091731/observable-of-array-find-index-of-value

Comment: Modified client.compoennt.ts as ngOnInit() {  
 Observable
  .interval(10000)
  .startWith(0)
  .switchMap(() => this.clientService.getAllInfo()).subscribe(clientInfo$ => this.clientInfo$ = clientInfo$  }
 
 }   and Changed client.component.html as  <table class="table table-hover" *ngIf="clientInfo$"> 
                    <tbody>
                        <tr *ngFor="let client of clientInfo$.realTimeClientInfo ">
                            <td *ngFor="let col of clientH"> {{client [col]}}</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>